# Besides retarded gravitation, anything else to worry about when calculating MU69's orbit from scratch?

Tags: gravity, mathematics, software, celestial-mechanics, 2014-mu69

For fun I'd like to use Hubble Astrometric data [for example the observations listed at the bottom here](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/db_search/show_object?object_id=486958) to numerically estimate the orbit of 2014 MU69 as well as its uncertainties.

My plan is to use some combination of [JPL Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi), Hubble's TLEs, and [Skyfield](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) to get the J2000.0 position of the HST at the time of each exposure, and to get the position of the sun and major planets to generate the gravity field in which to integrate MU69's motion.

I understand I will have to retard the gravity from each source by its particular light-time, as well as correct for the light time for the HST images.

This will not be fast or efficient, it's strictly an exercise. At each time step I'll have to iterate and interpolate to find out, just for example "where would Jupiter have been in it's orbit such that it's gravity would be arriving right now".

I'd do that and calculate an initial orbit for MU69, then use that to calculate apparent positions for the HST data, calculate an error, then try a different starting state vector for MU69 and see if that's better or worse, and just use steepest descent to find a nominal orbit. From that, I can see how sensitive the fit is to various combinations of deviations from nominal.

I'm aware there may be smarter ways to do this, but to appreciate them it's better to do it brute force at least once. In the age of giga-flop laptops it's a viable option.

**My question:** Are there other things I need to consider?

Just for example, do I need to worry about time moving at different speeds at different distances from the sun (general relativity) or forces on MU69 besides gravity from the Sun and outer planets *in order to get the level of accuracy relevant to comparison with the HST astrometry?*

**Again:** *...in order to get the level of accuracy relevant to comparison with the HST astrometry* — so I'm not looking for a list of arbitrarily small effects.

Comment: You might want to look over https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/index.html in particular how they note that computing light travel time doesn't make much of a difference. Also, you might want to use a numerical DFQ solver instead of the iteration you propose. I've done similar work for planets, nearly replicating Horizons' answers. Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: @barrycarter Thank you for those - I'll definitely take a look! I want to start by doing it in the lowest-tech way first, so that I can better appreciate more advanced algorithms in the future, but it's great to know they exist. I only let myself start using the scipy ODE methods after I wrote and tested an RK45 with automatic variable step size script myself first. It's just my way of learning how stuff works.

Comment: This object's orbit has a semimajor axis of 44 AU. Stated at the crudest level, we need general relativity rather than newtonian gravity when gravitational fields are strong. Therefore the outer solar system is the worst possible place to look if you're hoping to get fun, relativistic effects that need to be taken into account. This is why Mercury's orbit was a classic test of GR, and is also why the Shapiro time delay was measured for sun-grazing rays: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=1977JGR....82.4329S

Comment: @BenCrowell the calculation involves observation of MU69 at 44AU from the HST which is 1 AU from the Sun. So I'm asking about *the difference between 1 AU location and the 44 AU location*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a complete answer. It is instead an extended comment to the following:

> I understand I will have to retard the gravity from each source by its particular light-time, as well as correct for the light time for the HST images.

While you do want to correct for light time travel with regard to seeing a moving remote object, you definitely do not want to do the first part (retarded gravity). That is not how Newtonian mechanics works, nor is it not how general relativity works.

There is no lag in Newtonian mechanics; gravitation is instantaneous in Newtonian mechanics. In general relativity, there are some terms that act like lags, but there are other terms that act like leads. Those lag-like and lead-like terms in general relativity nearly cancel for small gravitational sources such as our Sun. That near cancelation is what makes Newtonian mechanics very close to correct. Keep in mind that the even for Mercury, the relativistic effect is very, very small: Only 43 arc seconds per century of precession that is not explainable by Newtonian mechanics.

A couple centuries ago, Laplace investigated whether gravitation is instantaneous. He found that adding any significant lag to Newtonian gravity makes the solar system become unstable in short order and this concluded that the speed of gravity had to be very high, at least $7\times10^{6}$ times the speed of light. A couple of decades ago, another highly respected astronomer published a paper in *Physics Letters A* (a highly respectable physics journal) that came to the conclusion that the speed of gravity is at least 20 billion times the speed of light.

Both Laplace and this more recent author were wrong. Laplace can be forgiven for not having possession of a time machine that would carry him a century into his future. The latter author cannot. His article has been cited 175 times (per google scholar), but almost all of the citations are essentially "You're wrong. So very, very wrong, and here's why ..." The "here's why" is that that is not the way general relativity works.

The easy way to solve what you are trying to do is to ignore relativistic effects. Just assume Newtonian physics, in which gravitation is instantaneous, but the speed of light is not.

The hard way is to incorporate general relativity, to some extent. You'll need a relativistically-correct time scale (e.g., JPL's T<sub>eph</sub>) and some kind of post-Newtonian model of gravitation that is, at least to first order, consistent with general relativity. For example, see [The Planetary and Lunar Ephemerides DE430 and DE431](ftp://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/planets/de430_and_de431.pdf). Do that and you'll be on par with the groups that develop extremely accurate solar system ephemerides.

Comment: To double check, are you saying that if I calculate the force based on where the Sun and outer planets would have been, *I'd get a worse result* than if I treat gravity as instantaneous, or just that that's not the best, most correct way to do it?

Comment: @uhoh - Adding a lag (and nothing else) **will** yield worse results (far worse results) than if you simply treat gravity as instantaneous. If you want to do GR right, you have to go whole hog. Well, almost whole hog. Except for very simple systems (e.g., a pair of neutron stars orbiting one another), nobody goes whole hog. They instead use some sort of post-Newtonian approximation or parameterized post-Newtonian formalism.

Comment: OK it's morning now for me and I've given your answer a fresh read, and I understand just what you are saying, though I don't mean to suggest I understand much about GR. This reminds me of a *read this some day* paper I've been holding on to. After learning about modeling non-gravitational forces on comets [for this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18438/12102) I've been meaning to try out Equation 1 in http://www.lpi.usra.edu/books/CometsII/7009.pdf (linked in comments there). It seems the second line is such a correction. In the mean time, I wont use a lag.

Comment: Thanks again for the comprehensive answer and history lesson to boot. As an aside, [somewhat related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/263244/83380) though it's a different question.

Comment: I just happened to see this recent question on GR and orbits. I don't know what it means, but that certainly resembles the approximation in [Equation 1](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/books/CometsII/7009.pdf) in my previous link. [Derivation of Post-Newtonian (PN) expression for acceleration in Schwarzschild geometry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/313146/83380).

Comment: Your previous reference used the Gaussian gravitational constant $k$ rather than $GM_E$ in the above. Otherwise, they're identical.

Comment: The Physics SE question has two equations, the first has $\beta$ and $\gamma$ which are said to both be unity in GR. I don't really understand the implications, so I thought it safer to say "resembles". Anyway I'll give it a go sometime soon, thanks for the encouragement!

Comment: I've [cited you](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/26841/7982), hopefully not out of context.

Comment: Your edit caused me to re-read your answer, and to be thankful that I mostly "publish" in SE question posts rather than Phys. Lett. A ;-) However now I am again worried. I use [this equation](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23409/12102) that you'd shown me earlier (the first-order post-Newtonian model of gravitation), but without giving any thought to "a relativistically-correct time scale". For Mercury it matches Horizons to 100 meters over one year, which is a good sign at least. Perhaps I should read more about Teph though.

Comment: Wery interesting! @David Hammen could you tell the lags cancel each other because of closed trajectories (=orbits)?

Comment: Are you saying there is a difference, for an object in relative motion, between the direction of "gravitational pull" and the direction from which an object's photons arrive at any given moment? Or in other words, between where an object appears to be gravitationally and where it appears to radiate from? (Assuming a perfect vacuum so that the photon speed is c.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Modeling gravity as having a speed of light lag delay is absolutely the worst thing one should do.

Comment: @DavidHammen That was a request for clarification rather than an expression of doubt ;-). Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHammen But allow me to request a follow-up clarification: Wouldn't then gravitation transmit certain information (namely about an object's position) faster than light? I'd be happy to ask a question over on physics SE but I'm afraid -- no, sure -- that I'm not understanding enough to even ask the question.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica General relativity has a concept of a static gravitational field. The Sun's static gravitation field has been there since the Sun first formed. It's also important to keep in mind that a scientific hypothesis that overturns a previous concept has to be consistent with that previous concept in areas where that previous concept was tested and validated. Newtonian gravity is a very good model. It misses the precession of Mercury by only 43 arc seconds per century. This is a very tiny amount. General relativity fully explains that 43 arc seconds per century precession.

Comment: Newtonian gravity implies that gravity propagates at an infinite speed. We now know that that is not the case, but it is a good model in the case of smallish masses (the Sun is a smallish mass) and largish distances (the distance between the Sun and Mercury is huge compared to the Sun's Schwarzschild radius).